# The type or namespace name 'IContextAccessor<HttpContext>' could not be found

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I've just moved my ASP.NET 5 project from beta2 to beta3.
After that the following code

```
public class AuthService : BaseService, IAuthService
{
    public AuthService(IContextAccessor<HttpContext> context) : base(context)
    {

    }
}
```

began to throw compilation error "**The type or namespace name 'IContextAccessor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**"
I use IContextAccessor to get HttpContext instance. 
`HttpContext context = context.Value;`
But as I understood this interface was removed from ASP.NET libraries.

Are there any similar ways to get HttpContext in beta3 release?

Comment: try `HttpContext.Current` static property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I was able to find the solution. I use `IHttpContextAccessor` to get `HttpContext`.

```
public BaseService(IHttpContextAccessor context)
{
        HttpContext context = context?.Value;
}
```

Comment: how did you set this up in `Startup`?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this error on `MyPage.cshtml` page where I was injecting `IHttpContextAccessor` without adding using directive for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`.

Adding the using directive fixed this for me:

```
@page
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
```